# Posting input field value through JS Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am having difficulties in returning an input field value through a JS function. It does return a value but it adds unnecessary information. How can I get echoed out the input value without other things? [EXAMPLE](http://webprolearner2346.zxq.net/registration-form/)

**JS**

```
   <script>
    $(function() {

    $(".submit").click(function() {

        var name = $("#name").val();                
        var dataString = 'name='+ name;

                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "jqueryform.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(result){
                $('#special').append('<p>' +  result + '</p>')  

                    }

               });
                return false;
           });     

    });
    </script>
```

**PHP**

```
 <?php
 if($_POST){
     $url     = $_POST['name'];
     echo ('What you type:&nbsp;&nbsp; <b>'.$url.'</b>');
    }
 ?>
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
 <input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="field text medium" value="" maxlength="255" tabindex="1"   />

<input  type="submit" value="Submit" style=" background:#0060a1; color:#FFFFFF; font-size:14px; border:1px solid #0060a1; margin-left:12px" class="submit"/>

<div id="special"> </div>

</html>
```

Comment: Try to add `header('Content-type: text/plain');` in `PHP`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change echo statement to:

```
echo ('What you type:&nbsp;&nbsp; <b><span id="resultval">'.$url.'</span></b>');
```

Change response method body to:

```
$('#special').append('<p>' +  $('#resultval', result).html() + '</p>');
```

Comment: Some how `echo ('What you type:&nbsp;&nbsp; <b>'<span id="resultval">.$url.</span>'</b>');` is giving me a syntax error : `unexpected T_STRING `

Comment: Sorry, quotes in wrong place. I've edited the post with typo corrected.

Comment: My mistake, use .html(). .val() doesn't appear to work with span. D'oh.

Comment: Thank you, I changed the code but It is not showing anything. I checked with firebug and it shows that the value is being assigned. You can check the update [EXAMPLE](http://webprolearner2346.zxq.net/registration-form/)

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be submitting the AJAX to a standard page, complete with the form. You would probably be better off just using a regular `<form>`, no AJAX, and it'll work exactly how you expect.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of echoing an plain php Use Json method

```
echo json_encode($rl);
```

and in the JS after the ajax call is complete decode the json encoded string and use it